# AWS lambda returns access denied when accessing S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a lambda function deployed as a container image. My lambda handler in the docker image is accessing my s3 bucket for downloading one or more files. When I invoke my lambda function locally using the boto3 lambda client, sometimes it works fine but sometimes it returns the error `{'errorMessage' : 'An error occurred (Access Denied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied', 'errorType':'ClientError'}`. The line of code it shows the error on is

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=file_path) ---> this line
```

My bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1657874069007",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1657874045596",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/service-role/<lambda_role_arn>"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also given the s3FullAccess role to my lambda function. I just don't understand what's happening, what's annoying is that how sometimes it works fine but sometimes it just starts giving this error. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? I am new to AWS. Also, if I run the lambda container image locally , this error doesn't occur at all.

Comment: Are you sure your lambda (not shown) always uses exact same bucket?

Comment: yes, I have declared the BUCKET_NAME variable at the top in the handler function itself. Its the same everytime

Comment: can you post all role policies attached to your function?

Comment: There is just a lambda basic execution role(for pushing cloud watch logs) and a AmazonS3FullAccess role attached to the lambda

Comment: Rather than using a Bucket Policy, it would be better to attach the S3 permissions to the IAM Role used by the Lambda function.  It is strange that your access "works sometimes" -- it should either always work, or never work.

Comment: I mean I did give s3FullAccess , isn't that enough ?  I agree its strange , that's why I am here

Comment: If it works sometimes, then my guess is you have it configured to run in a VPC, but some subnets of the VPC you have it configured to use don't have access to a NAT Gateway or S3 VPC Endpoint.

Comment: I didn't configure any VPC. I just deployed a container image, gave it s3FullAccess , gave a bucket policy to the bucket and started calling the function.

Comment: @MarkB I think you were correct. Its some VPC related issue. Do you know how to fix it ? Since I didn't configure VPC and I am a beginner, I don't really know.

Comment: If you didn't configure the Lambda to run in a VPC, then it's not a VPC related issue.

Comment: Then i guess there's no hope for me :( . I don't get why it works every single time locally though. What's so different about using a deployed lambda image than a local lambda image.